# How do I understand Invalid read in Valgrind, where address is bigger than the alloc'd block size

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I am new to Valgrind. Got these Valgrind message:

```
==932767== Invalid read of size 16
==932767==    at 0x3D97D2B9AA: __strcasecmp_l_sse42 (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
...
==932767==  Address 0x8c3e170 is 9 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd
==932767==    at 0x6A73B4A: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==932767==    by 0x34E821195A: ???
```

Here I have two questions:

1. the allocated block is 7 bytes, then how come the address 0x8c3e170 is in 9 bytes? Normally the pointed size is smaller than the allocated size. So under what circumstance we will meet the above issue?
2. the Invalide read size is 16bytes. Does it include the 2 extra bytes from "Address 0x8c3e170 is 9 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd"

Answer (score 3):

If it weren't for the ellipsis I would say the `Address 0x8c3e170...` msg is directly related to the `Invalid read of size 16` because it's indented further.

It's possible to get false positives, so don't rule that out.  For example, it's possible that strcasecmp is reading more than it needs to as an optimization.

I read the 2nd message as `the address being read from starts 9 bytes after the end of a block of size 7`.

I have two suggestions, either of which will probably help you track this down:

1) Run your application under valgrind such that you can attach in a separate terminal window with gdb:

```
~ valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 your_program
```

in another window:

```
~ gdb your_program
(gdb) target remote | vgdb
```

This option makes it halt as though a breakpoint were set on every problem valgrind finds

2) Compile with the undefined and/or memory sanitizers either with clang or gcc (4.9 or higher).  They catch the same sorts of issues, but I find the error messages more informative.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `...` is more stacktrace, rather than more Valgrind errors.

Comment: @Brian Thanks Brian! In regards to the second message, I thought it reads as the `address being read refers to 9 bytes, the allocated block size is 7 bytes`.

Comment: @rocketjumper The way I interpreted it is more in line with what I've seen in practice.  Whenever you see `invalid read of size X`, it means the instruction executed attempted to read `X` bytes all at once.  As an example, one of the optimizations clang performs for `char blah[4096] = {}` is to zero large registers and use SSE instructions to store a large number of bytes to a memory address.  Under certain [strange] circumstances the stack was only 4 byte aligned, but the SSE instructions were emitted under the assumption the stack was 16-byte aligned.  (contd)

Comment: When I said it might be an optimization in `strcasecmp`, this is what I'm referring to; it may be using instructions that load 16 bytes at a time, even if it over-reads (eg, by 9 bytes).

Comment: Given the function name `__strcasecmp_l_sse42`, I would hazard that it _is_ optimized to use SIMD instructions that likely over-read.  Though, in such cases (and in my experience), there's not normally a read that _begins_ after the _end_ of the string unless the terminating NUL has gone awry.

Comment: @TobySpeight Good point, I completely ignored the rest of the function name.